# How many tennis players have finished the year as Slam-less World No. 1?

Tags: trivia, tennis, atp, wta, grand-slam

Roger Federer is very close, theoretically & somewhat practically, to finishing the calender year as World No. 1 without winning a Grand Slam 
this year.

How many tennis players (both men & women) in the open era of tennis history have finished a calender year as World No. 1 without winning
any of the Grand Slams in that particular calender year? 
Remember that the question includes the "Career Slam-less" as well as "Year Slam-less" World No. 1 at the **end of the year**.

At the top of my mind I remember, Caroline Wozniacki & Dinara Safina finishing No. 1 in womens tennis.

Comment: [Players who have held the No1 ranking without holding (reigning) a GS title?](http://www.menstennisforums.com/showthread.php?t=435681) at menstennisforums and [Ranking the Careers of This Era's Slamless Number Ones and One-Slam Wonders](http://www.tennisforum.com/showthread.php?t=620577) at tennisforum. Although it is not exactly the same question, you might find some useful information there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**ATP Tour**

Simply by checking [List of ATP number 1 ranked singles players](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ATP_number_1_ranked_singles_players#Year-end_no._1) at Wikipedia I found two players who were Year-end No. 1 without winning a Grand Slam tournament that year:

- [Jimmy Connors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jimmy_Connors#Career_statistics) in [1975](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1975_Grand_Prix_(tennis)) and [1977](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1977_Grand_Prix_(tennis))
- [John McEnroe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_McEnroe#Career_statistics) in [1982](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1982_Grand_Prix_(tennis))

(Connors won his first GS title in 1974 and McEnroe in 1979. But they did not won any GS in the years listed above. Note that McEnroe did not start at French Open and Australian Open in that year. So did Connors in 1977. In 1975 Connor did not play French Open.)

The same Wikipedia article also mentions [two players](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ATP_number_1_ranked_singles_players#Players_who_were_ranked_world_no._1_without_having_won_a_Grand_Slam_tournament) who were at No. 1 position without GS title: Marcelo Rios and Ivan Lendl. (Lendl won several Grand Slam tournaments later.)

[This article](http://www.ubitennis.com/english/2014/10/14/can-federer-become-world-number-1/) also says that: *Federer could become the oldest Number 1 player since André Agassi. He could also become the third player to end the year in Number 1 position without winning a Grand Slam title after Jimmy Connors in 1975 and 1977 and John McEnroe in 1982.*

---

**WTA Tour**

By checking [similar list for WTA Tour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_WTA_number_1_ranked_players#Singles) on Wikipedia we can find the following year-end No. 1's without GS in the same year

- [Monica Seles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monica_Seles_career_statistics#Singles_performance_timeline) in [1995](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1995_WTA_Tour).
- [Martina Hingis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martina_Hingis_career_statistics#Performance_timeline) in [2000](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2000_WTA_Tour).
- [Lindsay Davenport](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindsay_Davenport_career_statistics#Singles_performance_timeline) in [2001](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2001_WTA_Tour), [2004](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2004_WTA_Tour) and [2005](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2005_WTA_Tour).
- [Jelena Jankovic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jelena_Jankovi%C4%87#Career_statistics) in [2008](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2008_WTA_Tour).
- [Caroline Wozniacki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caroline_Wozniacki#Career_statistics) in [2010](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2010_WTA_Tour) and [2011](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2011_WTA_Tour).

Note that Jankovic and Wozniacki still have not won a GS tournament. (Seles won her first GS title in 1990, Hingis in 1997 and Davenport in 1998.)

It is also worth mentioning 1995 was the comeback year for Monika Seles after the stabbing incident and she only played one GS tournament (US Open). She is listed as year-end No. 1 by WTA together with Steffi Graf (despite having less points than her).

The same Wikipedia article lists [5 players](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_WTA_number_1_ranked_players#Players_who_were_ranked_world_No._1_without_having_won_a_Grand_Slam_tournament) that were ranked No. 1 without having a GS title at the time: Kim Clijsters, Amélie Mauresmo, Jelena Jankovic, Dinara Safina and Caroline Wozniacki. (Clijster and Mauresmo won several GS tournaments, but only after they became No. 1 for the first time.)

[This blog post](http://www.womenstennisblog.com/2011/12/31/hingis-and-davenport-were-just-as-slamless-no-1s-as-jankovic-safina-and-wozniacki-and-nobody-criticized-them-part-2-of-analysis/) discusses slamless No.1's since 2000.

Comment: I hope I did not miss some player when going through those two lists.

Comment: nice answer and research, well done.

Comment: Nicely researched answer. Although the 1st link redirects to WTA No. 1 & not ATP. So you might edit the link

Comment: @KharoBangdo Thanks for noticing that. It should be corrected now.

Answer (score 2):

There is an answer summarizing the situation at the time when the question was posted. Here is a CW answer which can be updated when there are more players with No. 1 position without Grand Slam title.

### Men

#### Year-end No. 1 without Grand Slam title in the same year

See also [the list on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ATP_number_1_ranked_singles_tennis_players#No._1_ranked_players_without_a_previous_Grand_Slam_title) ([revision from 2019](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=List_of_ATP_number_1_ranked_singles_tennis_players&oldid=918758524#No._1_ranked_players_without_a_previous_Grand_Slam_title)).

- [Jimmy Connors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jimmy_Connors#Career_statistics) in 1975 and 1977
- [John McEnroe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_McEnroe#Career_statistics) in 1982

#### No. 1 position before the first Grand Slam title

- [Ivan Lendl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ivan_Lendl) (No. 1 in 1983, the first GS title in 1984)
- [Marcelo Ríos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marcelo_R%C3%ADos) (No. 1 in 1998, no GS title)

### Women

#### Year-end No. 1 without Grand Slam title in the same year

- [Monica Seles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monica_Seles_career_statistics#Singles_performance_timeline) in 1995.
- [Martina Hingis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martina_Hingis_career_statistics#Performance_timeline) in 2000.
- [Lindsay Davenport](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindsay_Davenport_career_statistics#Singles_performance_timeline) in 2001, 2004 and 2005.
- [Jelena Jankovic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jelena_Jankovi%C4%87#Career_statistics) in 2008.
- [Caroline Wozniacki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caroline_Wozniacki#Career_statistics) in 2010 and 2011.
- [Simona Halep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simona_Halep) in 2017.

#### No. 1 position before the first Grand Slam title

See also [the list on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_WTA_number_1_ranked_tennis_players#Players_who_became_No._1_before_winning_their_first_Grand_Slam) ([revision from 2019](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=List_of_WTA_number_1_ranked_tennis_players&oldid=919296962#Players_who_became_No._1_before_winning_their_first_Grand_Slam)).

- [Amélie Mauresmo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Am%C3%A9lie_Mauresmo) (No. 1 in 2004, the first GS title in 2006)
- [Kim Clijsters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kim_Clijsters) (No. 1 in 2003, the first GS title in 2005)
- [Jelena Jankovic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jelena_Jankovi%C4%87) (No. 1 in 2008, no GS title)
- [Dinara Safina](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dinara_Safina) (No. 1 in 2009, no GS title)
- [Caroline Wozniacki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caroline_Wozniacki) (No. 1 in 2010, the first GS title in 2018)
- [Karolína Plíšková](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karol%C3%ADna_Pl%C3%AD%C5%A1kov%C3%A1) (No. 1 in 2017, no GS title)
- [Simona Halep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simona_Halep) (No. 1 in 2017, the first GS title in 2018)

### Sources

Wikipedia articles [List of ATP number 1 ranked singles tennis players](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ATP_number_1_ranked_singles_tennis_players) and [List of WTA number 1 ranked tennis players](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_WTA_number_1_ranked_tennis_players).

Comment: This answer is [community wiki](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/community-wiki/info) - feel free to edit/update it whenever needed.