# How many times a tennis player became world number one ranking without ever winning a grand slam?

Tags: tennis, history, ranking, atp, wta

Tennis world number ones are usually grand slam champions, Roger Federer, Serina Williams, and Andy Murray are a few examples. But it's possible for a player to become the top seed collecting points by making deep runs in the grand slams and winning non major titles.

Has there been a time when a man or a woman reached singles first seed before ever winning a major? If so please list them all, also did they to win a grand slam afterwards?

Comment: I commented on the answer below to add some information about WTA Players. On the ATP (Mens) side - the only player I know of to achieve world number one without ever winning a grand slam event was Marcelo Rios.

Comment: This is rather similar to the older question here: [How many tennis players have finished the year as Slam-less World No. 1?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/q/6933) You can find also links to some relevant Wikipedia articles there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**ATP**:

- [Ivan Lendl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ivan_Lendl) was the only player in the list who has won singles
  grand slams prior to Wozniacki winning her only slam in 2018. He's known as one of the greatest players ever, holding
  the world #1 for 270 weeks (the 3rd most all time by a male player).
  He reached #1 seed first time in 1983. In 1984 he won his first grand
  slam at the French Open after four major finals losses. Lendl has won
  8 majors championships, having won all grand slams except for
  Wimbledon.
- [Marcelo Rios](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marcelo_R%C3%ADos) was the top seed for only 6 weeks in 1998. In his
  only grand slam finals appearance he lost to Petr Korda in the 1998
  Australian Open.

**WTA**:

- [Caroline Wozniacki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caroline_Wozniacki) finished 2010 and 2011 as the top seed, in
  total she's been the world #1 for 67 weeks. Despite winning 25 WTA
  titles, she's never won a grand slam. Her only grand slam finals
  happened in the US open in 2009 and 2014. **EDIT**: Before retiring, Wozniacki won the 2018 Australian Open. The championship propelled her to the #1 ranking once more, but this time as a grand slam champion.
- [Jelena Jankovic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jelena_Jankovi%C4%87) reached the top seed in 2008 and finished the
  year in that spot, making her the first player in WTA to finish a
  year as world #1 without wining a grand slam. Her only singles majors
  finals was the 2008 US open. It is noteworthy that she won a grand
  slam in mixed doubles of 2007 Wimbledon with Jamie Murray.
- [Dinara Safina](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dinara_Safina) became world #1 in 2009. She made the most singles
  grand slam finals without a championship among the players in this
  list. She was the runner up in 2008 and 2009 French Open as well as
  the 2009 Australian Open. Similar to Jankovic, Safina's only majors
  championship came in the doubles. She won the 2007 US open women's doubles
  with Nathalie Dechy.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. [Caroline Wozniacki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caroline_Wozniacki) was number one on the WTA Tour for 67 weeks but has never won a Grand Slam title, her best results being runner-up at the US Open in 2009 and 2014.

Comment: Yes, she is the reason I ask the question. Watching Wimbledon it was mentioned she has never won a major and I recalled she was ranked #1 for a long time - finished #1 two years in a row I believe. What I'm really wondering is that if she's the only person ever

Comment: I'm pretty sure Jelena Jankovic and Dinara Safina both made it to WTA #1 and neither of them won a major title either.